# Geocode returns no Value

Tags: android

I'm trying to convert address to long and lat, but it is returning 0. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
geocoder = new Geocoder(this);  
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
        try {
            EditText loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            String locationName = loc.getText().toString();             
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 2);              
            if(addressList!=null && addressList.size()>0) {
                lat = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1000000);
                lng = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1000000);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lattitude = Integer.toString(lat);          
        longertude = Integer.toString(lng);
```

My LOGCAT :

```
07-03 13:44:28.799: I/System.out(274): [INFO:19529614]: LogSource: Running flush
07-03 13:44:28.799: I/System.out(274): [INFO:19529623]: LogSource: Sending payload [bytes=267]
07-03 13:44:32.262: D/SntpClient(83): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-03 13:44:33.809: I/System.out(274): [INFO:19534623]: LogSource: Running delayed flush
07-03 13:44:33.809: W/System.err(2517): java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
07-03 13:44:33.823: I/System.out(274): [INFO:19534640]: LogSource: Running flush
07-03 13:44:33.829: I/System.out(274): [INFO:19534651]: LogSource: Sending payload [bytes=267]
07-03 13:44:33.869: W/System.err(2517):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
07-03 13:44:33.869: W/System.err(2517):     at de.vogella.android.locationapi.simple.InsertStock$1.onClick(InsertStock.java:108)
07-03 13:44:33.879: W/System.err(2517):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-03 13:44:33.891: W/System.err(2517):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
07-03 13:44:33.899: W/System.err(2517):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-03 13:44:33.899: W/System.err(2517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 13:44:33.899: W/System.err(2517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-03 13:44:33.913: W/System.err(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
07-03 13:44:33.919: W/System.err(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 13:44:33.939: W/System.err(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-03 13:44:33.939: W/System.err(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-03 13:44:33.939: W/System.err(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-03 13:44:33.939: W/System.err(2517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But there is no errors (red words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed locationName number to 2

```
try 
        {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(searchedAddress,**2**);
            if (address == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "############Address not correct #########");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get Lat, Long from address :

```
    public String getLatitudeAndLongitudeFromGoogleMapForAddress(String searchedAddress){

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> address;
        try 
        {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(searchedAddress,5);
            if (address == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "############Address not correct #########");
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "Address Latitude : "+ location.getLatitude() + "Address Longitude : "+ location.getLongitude());

            for(int i = 0; i<address.size();i++)
            {
                 Address location2 = address.get(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "Address  : "+ location2.getAddressLine(0));
            }

            return "lat="+ location.getLatitude() +"&long="+ location.getLongitude();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "MY_ERROR : ############Address Not Found");
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

And if you are tying it in Android Emulator then it will not work :
It's a [bug in the emulator for 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816)

Comment: did you set internet permission?

Comment: yes i did, as i said it was working , but now it does not work, i dont why

Comment: Is there any kind of Log in LogCat?

Comment: Try adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml as well:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

And also try your app in a Device. Maybe its a emulator fault.

Comment: I removed the connection from my emulator coz i was checking my emails connections. then i connect it back then it started working again.. u just but your address then it convert into lat and long.